# Node application runs on Heroku but not localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack

I have a simple REST API using MEAN. It's hosted on Heroku, and everything works well there. However, if I try to run it on localhost I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
at Url.parse (url.js:81:11)
at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:75:5)
at module.exports (/Users/ricardotaboada/Desktop/sbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:15:23)
at connect (/Users/ricardotaboada/Desktop/sbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:403:16)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/ricardotaboada/Desktop/sbackend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:227:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ricardotaboada/Desktop/sbackend/server.js:15:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks very much.

EDIT: Here is the code that connects to Mongo:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
process.exit(1);
}

sbrdcontroller = new controller(database);
console.log("Database connection ready");

// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
var port = server.address().port;
console.log("App now running on port", port);


  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing some code.

That said, from the error message it sounds like you're not passing a valid URL to connect to your mongodb.

EDIT:

Right, so based on your code, check the value of `process.env.MONGODB_URI`.  You can do that from your heroku account or cli, or by `console.log`, but I'm betting it's not set on your heroku app.  Depending on the Mongo addin you use, they use different environment variable names.

Answer (score 0):

process.env.MONGODB_URI is undefined in your local environment which is why the error is being thrown.

Add this code before the database connection code:

```
var development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

var mongo_url;

if (development) {
    mongo_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
}
else {
    mongo_url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}
```

Then change:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
```

To:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, function (err, database) {
```

Assuming your local Mongo database port was not changed, the local URL with port 27017 should work fine.

Now your code should work fine in both development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dotenv module will be useful for you:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv